# Twitter bootstrap modal call controller action

Tags: ajax, grails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popup window using twitter bootstrap modal. I want to call an controller action before the display of the popup and display the value of the variable from the controller action into the popup. The ajax is not calling the controller action. Is there other way to do it?

My gsp:

```
<g:javascript>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#myModal').on('show', function () {
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "${createLink(controller: 'mGMatrices', action: 'popup')}" 
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#modal-body').html(data);
            });

          });//end on()
        });//end ready()
      </g:javascript>

       <g:textField name="inputField" />
      <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
      <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>


      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <p>some content</p>
             <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfect and it works for me after a minor change in the code.

You are using # that represents the id not the class.

```
$('#modal-body').html(data);
```

replace # with .

e.g

```
$('.modal-body').html(data);
```

Try this and enjoy.............

**EDIT.............................................................................**

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "${createLink(controller: 'mGMatrices', action: 'popup')}",
          data: "inputField="+$("[name='inputField']").val()+"&fieldName="+$("[name='fieldNAme']").val()
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#modal-body').html(data);
        });
```

Comment: It works. But i need to get the textbox input inside the controller. When i print params.inputField its still null.

Comment: wow, that's great. Another thing, I need to call first the action in the controller before displaying the popup. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question in comment:

```
I need to call first the action in the controller before displaying the popup.
```

Ans: Change  your code slightly as explained.

```
<g:javascript>
    function callMe(){
      $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "${createLink(controller: 'mGMatrices', action: 'popup')}",
      data: "aa="+$("[name='inputField']").val()
        }).success(function(data) {
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    }
</g:javascript>

<g:textField name="inputField"/>
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="callMe()">Launch demo modal</a>



<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some content</p>
        <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I have one last concern. On the controller action I have a return value and I need that return value to be displayed in the popup window. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have used return key word in your controller then please replace it with render and you will get value(as i think). One more thing if you got your problem solved then please vote up the answer.